# Android : NullPointerException when switching to other apps

Tags: android

This example work well. But when i switch to other applications, then i come back, myMethod throw a null pointer exception. How can i get the reference to the FragmentPagerAdapter?

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private FragmentPagerAdapter tabAdapter;

    private final BroadcastReceiver onNotice = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           myMethod();
        }
    };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter();
    }

    protected void myMethod() {
        tabAdapter.getCount(); // <-- NullPointerException
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: From where do you call `myMethod()`?

Comment: I didn't post all the code, from a TextButton

Comment: It would help if you show a bit more of the source code. Without it will be hard to say why `myMethod()` is being called before `onCreate()`.

Comment: i added the call of myMethod(), i didn't put all the code because it contains more than 300 lignes. so i put just the essential.

Comment: At least for me is impossible to figure out the problem because the source code do not show where you do register/unregister the `BroadcastReceiver`. To be more effective, I would advise you to reduce your code to a minimum where others can copy and paste to reproduce the error. If I copy and paste the code above, nothing will happen.

Comment: Have you ever tried this?  
 `private static FragmentPagerAdapter tabAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(); `

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to call

```
tabAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter();
```

in

```
onResume()
```

Comment: but in the screen there is always the FragmentPagerAdapter and other views already instanciated, can't i just get the reference instead of recreating them all?

Comment: I think when the activity enters the background, the FragmentPagerAdapter gets destroyed, therefore your variable points to nothing. I can't try it myselfe, as this is not my development machine.